# PHP weird situation while assigning vars into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building a SQL query. Weird thing is that some vars are being assigned correctly or wrongly depending on their position inside the array. Here's the code:

```
$v = [...] // $v is an array containing a serialized form
$id = 20;
foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
    $key = explode('c_', $key);
    $key = $key[1]; // this is the id of the fieldset that is being processed
    // array containing the data to be inserted with the query
    $data = array(
        'a'         => (empty($v['a_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['a_'.$key]), 
        'b'         => (empty($v['b_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['b_'.$key]), 
        'c'         => $value,
        'd'         => (empty($v['d_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['d_'.$key]), 
        'e'         => (empty($v['e_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['e_'.$key]),
        'id'        => $id
    );
    // array containing the format of the data of the array $data
    $format = array(
        (empty($v['a'.$key]) ? NULL : '%s'),
        (empty($v['b_'.$key]) ? NULL : '%s'),
        '%s',
        (empty($v['d_'.$key]) ? NULL : '%s'),
        (empty($v['e_'.$key]) ? NULL : '%s'),
        '%d'
    );
    [...] // then i send the query to the db
}
```

What happens here is:

- if all the data that is going to be assigned returns `false` from the `empty()` check (and so they are NOT NULL), everything works fine;
- if I omit the data before the `'c' => $value`, everything works fine. Example:

  ```
  $data = array(
      'c'         => $value,
      'd'         => (empty($v['d_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['d_'.$key]), 
      'e'         => (empty($v['e_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['e_'.$key]),
      'id'        => $id
  );
  ```
- if I assign `'c' => $value` and `'id' => $id` BEFORE all the other variables, everything works fine. Example:

  ```
  $data = array(
      'c'         => $value,
      'id'        => $id,
      'a'         => (empty($v['a_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['a_'.$key]), 
      'b'         => (empty($v['b_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['b_'.$key]), 
      'd'         => (empty($v['d_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['d_'.$key]), 
      'e'         => (empty($v['e_'.$key]) ? NULL : $v['e_'.$key])
  );
  ```
- in all the other case, using the code as displayed at the beginning of this question, `c` and `id` will be set as `''`.

Of course I tried to echo both `$value` and `$id`: both of them are correctly assigned. This is something really weird!

**UPDATE**

Here's an example of the `var_dump($v)`, as per Kim's request:

```
array (size=[...])
  [...]
  'a_0' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'b_0' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'c_0' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'd_0' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'e_0' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'a_1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'b_1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'c_1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'd_1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'e_1' => string 'test' (length=4)
  [...]
```

Moreover, I also tried to assigning the value directly like this `'c' => 'This is a test'` and it is always returning `''` into the final array. I think this is a proof that the problem is inside the code posted, as per Jason's doubt.

Comment: How are you sure it's this part of the code and not something else that changes `$data`?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary because that is all the code involved in the situation.

Comment: Then the underlying data (`$v`) is not what you think it is. It's more likely *you* are doing something wrong that *PHP*. Add some trace statements to see where the data breaks down.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary that's what i did: i echo the data when they are returned wrong. Then i tried to leave only those data to simplify the scenario. That's how i end up with the scenario explained in the question. What else do you suggest to do?

Comment: so, now with your provided data it has sense to change line `$keyArr = explode('_', $index);` check my updated answer :-)

Answer (score -4):

first of all, that is bad practice to reassign var inside the loop and during the loop

so your code:

```
foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
    $key = explode('c_', $key);
    $key = $key[1]; // this is the id of the fieldset that is being processed
```

must replaced with:

```
foreach ($v as $index => $value) {
    $keyArr = explode('_', $index);
    $key = $keyArr[1]; // this is the id of the fieldset that is being processed
```

That would make your code more readable with no confusion.

By the way, are you sure that you need really `foreach ($v[]`?

For me it seems better to be changed to:

```
$executedKey=null;
foreach ($v as $index => $value) {
        $keyArr = explode('_', $index);
        $key = $keyArr[1];
        if ($key == $executedKey) {
          continue;
        } else {
           $executedKey = $key;
        };
```

So with your `$v` sample it will loop just 2 times, not 10.

Comment: Is this really an answer and not a comment? The suggestion (while entirely true) above shouldn't change the behaviour of the code itself, right?

Comment: @Rangad  yes it is real answer. And it  will change a lot :-) check the data source provided by Mariano and my last update. Clear vision - Clear code - Clear result.

Comment: @KimAlexander i've updated my code as per your suggestions, but the situation isn't changed

Comment: you did replace 'c_' with '_' and behavior didn't change?

Comment: for me that changed everything. could you provide full fragment of your current code? did you implement `continue`?

Comment: @KimAlexander yep...don't worry about it. I will assign it at the beginning of the array. That's not a so important application and it can stay this "buggy" way. I've already loose too much time on it for the moment. Moreover a lot of people here seems to have fun downvoting others questions...and this is so sad! Thanks for your time Kim

Comment: I don't worry about downvoting, I just see that `c_` can't work for the first element in your array where `index` is `a_0`, but `_` work, and that fix completely explain weird behavior of your code especially starting from `c` element of your array, and I am pretty sure that if you can show your current version of code I can help you.